# Shibboleth Service Provider 2.3.8 - Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Tags: windows, apache, shibboleth

I am trying to build up a testing environment in which I could manage the login to my web application using Shibboleth. I managed to configure and install Shibboleth IdP (2.3.8) under Tomcat 6 and now I am trying to install and configure Shibboleth Service Provider (2.5.2). I managed to install the software but when I try to start the Shibboleth SP service (I am using Windows XP SP3) It returns the error in the title.
I'm following instruction from Shibboleth official wiki step by step but I can't figure out the cause of this error.

I am completely new to this kind of technology so keep in mind that I could miss something big :D

Could you guide me in troubleshooting this kind of problem?

I already tried to raise the timeout time putting a registry key but It doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: It will help if you could provide your config files, or at the very least, any changes you've made to your config files.  Also, please show the exact error you're receiving.  If you receive an error on screen, there should be an error in the logs.  Review the logs, and post them if applicable.

Comment: try to see logs of apache and/or shibboleth and come with infra/config and exact error.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found using Shibboleth 2 doc. that there could be issues with Shibboleth installation and configuration under Windows XP SP3 environment. I downloaded the SP 2.3.1 version in Shibboleth's archives and I managed to install It properly. Sadly the service does not start anyway, but It seems the cause is a Shibboleth2.xml configuration problem. But that's another story... Sorry for the silly question, I hope It could be of help for someone else.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question or add "SOLVED" to the title. Add the answer as an answer. You can get the solution from the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36604247/revisions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a solution.
Sorry for my silly question but I hope It could be of help for someone else.

It seems that incompatibility issues between Shibboleth 2.3.8 and Windows XP SP3 prevents It to be installed. I managed to install the SP downloading Shibboleth 2.3.1 SP from Shibboleth's archive.